# HIghcharts how to change values and ranges in the Y-axis

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to do this chart:
[image]

But I can't manage to get the same values and ranges in the Y axis. I need the values to be exactly 100 000, 200 000, 300 000, etc.. how can I achieve that? Please see code. Thanks in advance.

```css
//Grafica 1
$(function () {
var yAxisLabels = [0,100000,200000,300000,400000,500000,600000,700000,800000,900000];
var categories= ['1990', '2000', '2010', '2020', '2030', '2040', '2050'];
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
           labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          min: '0',
          title: {
            text: 'Percentage'
          },
          tickPositioner: function() {
                    return yAxisLabels;
                }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [100000, 100000, 500000, 900000, 900000, 900000, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [100000, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [25020, 296350, 100000, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [25020, 296350, 100000, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [100000, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 100000, 555268]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use formatter in yAxis

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5vfa3o0o/2/)

```
$(function () {
var yAxisLabels = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100];
var categories= ['1350', '1400', '1450', '1500', '1550', '1699', '1750'];
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
           labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
         yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          min: '0',
          title: {
            text: 'Percentage'
          },
          tickPositioner: function() {
                    return yAxisLabels;
                },
          labels: {
            formatter: function(){
              return 100*this.value / $(this.axis.tickPositions).last()[0] + '%';
            }
          }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
            split: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'percent',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                }
            },
             column: { stacking:'percent', pointPadding: 0.2, borderWidth: 0 }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
        }]
    });
});
```

**Update With New Requirement**

[image: Updated image]
Change `stacking: 'percentage',` to `stacking: 'normal',`

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kovs4k8b/1/)

so final code

```
$(function () {
var yAxisLabels = [0,1000000,2000000,3000000,4000000,5000000,6000000,7000000,8000000,9000000];
var categories= ['1990', '2000', '2010', '2020', '2030', '2040', '2050'];
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
           labels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function () {
                    return categories[this.value];
                }
            },
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
          allowDecimals: false,
          min: '0',
          title: {
            text: 'Y-AXIS'
          },
          tickPositioner: function() {
                    return yAxisLabels;
                },
          labels: {
            formatter: function(){
              return this.value;
            }
          }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                lineColor: '#ffffff',
                lineWidth: 1,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    lineColor: '#ffffff',
                }
            }
        },
           series: [{
            name: 'Africa',
            data: [100000, 100000, 500000, 900000, 900000, 900000, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'L. America',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Oceania',
            data: [100000, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'S-E. Asia',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Japan',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'China',
            data: [25020, 296350, 100000, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Near East',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Asian CIS',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Russia',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'East Europe',
            data: [25020, 296350, 100000, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Central Europe',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'W. Europe - Nordic',
            data: [25020, 100000, 222809, 241947, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'Nordic',
            data: [100000, 296350, 222809, 100000, 331402, 443634, 555268]
        }, {
            name: 'N. America',
            data: [25020, 296350, 222809, 241947, 331402, 100000, 555268]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried what you said but now it is not graphing the points. See new code I just added. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: why yAxisLabels lables have such high values. percentage is calculated out of 100 or you want `100000%,200000%,` etc in yAxis. Please update picture in question

Comment: Sorry I updated the chart I am trying to do.. Is not with % anymore. See chart above. Thanks

Comment: Updated with new requirement , check it

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way to go about this is using the `tickInterval` attribute:

```
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Percent'
    },
    tickInterval: 10,
    labels: {
        formatter: function(){
            return this.value + '%';
        }
    }
},
```

That will force your axis intervals to show up as you requested.

I hope this helps!

Comment: @Bastcri It looks like your requirements have changed since I posted my answer. Would it be helpful to update what I've written? I see Deep 3015 was able to get you what you needed.